# Путаница в понятиях и терминах

Tags: ономастика, существительные, приложение, определения

> Плыву по красавице Волге!

Есть четкое правило, которое позволяет найти приложение в тексте:

"При сочетании нарицательного и собственного имени неодушевлённых предметов приложением является имя собственное".

> река **Волга** (Волга – приложение)

Не могу понять, почему тогда в первом случае приложением является "красавица"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу пока так, как понимаю значение термина. Будут нужны ссылки – добавлю.

**Приложение** – это та или иная характеристика предмета (субъекта, объекта), выполняет синтаксическую функцию определения. А значит, при его изъятии основной смысл не пострадает.

*Плыву по Волге.* (Не по красавице же плыть.)
По какой Волге? – красивой, по **красавице** Волге, по Волге-**красавице**, по Волге-**матушке**.

*Плыву по реке.*
По какой реке, какой именно? – **Волге**.

Comment: Почему это правило не работает в данном случае? Падеж ведь мог бы быть и именительный, тогда бы смысл не помог.

Comment: @Ajgy Как не работает? Всё работает. "Река **Волга** впадает в...", "**Красавица** Волга впадает в..."

Comment: А если так: "Красавица Волга нас очаровала!". Очаровать может и красавица.

Comment: Да и к тому же мы можем вынести сочетание в название: "Красавица Волга", Тогда этот способ не работает, но определить, где приложение. мы должны.

Comment: @Ajgy Ну нельзя же так просто относиться к тексту, мы же не роботы (хотя они сейчас ого-го!). Контекст, знания названий, здравый смысл подскажут, где главное слово, а где его определение.

Comment: Вернемся к тому же вопросу. Дано только название - красавица Волга. Как быть? Нет подсказок? Есть только лишь правило, почему оно не работает тогда?

Comment: Почему нельзя сказать так: красавица (какая) Волга? Ведь с рекой мы можем сделать то же самое.

Comment: @Ajgy Волга не относится к красавицам, нельзя характеризовать красавицу названием реки. Волга – река. Река – ее категория, родовое понятие.

Comment: Приложение - это же не только род и вид: охотник-путешественник. Мы же субъективно смотрим на слова, выделяем то, что является более широким с нашей точки зрения.

Comment: @Ajgy Про род я написал к тому, что это один из видов, встречающихся среди темы приложений. И к тому, что "красавица" в данном случае не родовое слово, а самое что ни на есть характеризующее слово. Красивая женщина, красивая река. Ну, в конце концов, смысл же рулит.

Comment: Непонятно тогда, почему в правиле не указали, что оценочные существительные, заменяемые прилагательными, являются приложениями.

Comment: @Ajgy Не могу сказать, в правилах вообще невозможно всё прописать. А вот здесь, например, имя будет приложением: "Пришла еще одна красавица, **Маша**". Уточняющий характер.

Comment: Этот случай описан, о нем знаю. Очень странная система с этими приложениями. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Ajgy  Да, было время тут, когда я тоже мучился этим вопросом. Спасибо!

Comment: @Ajgy  А! Про оценочное наверняка видели у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111) (пункт 4, 1): "...предшествующее однословное приложение может быть по значению приравнено к определению-прилагательному: красавец мужчина (ср.: красивый мужчина), старик отец, гигант завод".

Comment: Да. Это понятно, просто не думал, что может относиться и к собственным именам существительным.

Answer (score 0):

Слово ‟красавица” в данном предложении является нарицательным (нарицательное – любое неименное существительное). Это метафора, и в данном предложении это слово обозначает что-то, что вызывает положительные впечатления, или что-то подобное. Вероятнее всего, некий грамотей впал в недоумение из-за того, является ли в данном случае ‟красавица” нарицательным, выпал за текстуры, а потом написал это. В данном случае это ошибка в том источнике, где указано, что ‟Волга” – это приложение. Есть железное правило про определение приложения и определяемого слова, и какие-то сложности или неопределённости никому в подобных ситуациях не нужны. Если же лингвисты хотят так выстраивать терминологию, то есть считать в таких ситуациях слово ‟Волга” определяемым словом, что будет просто грубой условностью и бесполезным бзиком некого лингвиста, то они обязаны писать об этом в любом учебнике по синтаксису либо не спрашивать об этом на каком-либо тестировании. Лингвиста хлебом не корми, а дай изобрести на ровном месте какое-нибудь никому не нужное исключение.